# redrawing canvas html5 without flickering

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, redraw

I've a screen being redraw every 25ms, and images are flickering, here is my code

```
                var FRAME_RATE = 40;
                var intervalTime = 1000/FRAME_RATE;
                gameLoop();

                function gameLoop(){
                    context.clearRect(0, 0, 640, 640);
                    renderMap();
                    window.setTimeout(gameLoop, intervalTime);  
                }
```

and here is renderMap() function

```
function renderMap(){
                    var startX = playerX - (screenW / 2);
                    var startY = playerY - (screenH / 2);

                    maxX = playerX + (screenW / 2);
                    maxY = playerY + (screenH / 2);
                    $.getJSON('mapa3.json', function(json){
                        for (x = startX; x < maxX; x=x+32){ 
                            for (y = startY; y < maxY; y=y+32){
                                intTile = json.layers[0].data[((y/32)* 100) + (x/32)];
                                context.putImageData(getTile(intTile - 1), x - startX, y - startY);
                            }
                        } 
                    });

                    var imgCharacter = new Image();
                    imgCharacter.src = 'char.png';

                    var posX = (screenW - imgCharacter.width) / 2;
                    var posY = (screenH - imgCharacter.height) / 2;
                    imgCharacter.onload = function(){context.drawImage(imgCharacter, posX, posY)}       
                }
```

What changes do I need to make to the code to stop flickering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it is because you are loading the image each iteration. Try putting the `var imgCharacter...`, the following line, and the image's `onload` function outside of `renderMap` so it is only ran once

```
var imgCharacter = new Image();    
imgCharacter.onload = function () {
    renderMap();
}
imgCharacter.src = 'char.png';

function renderMap() {
    var startX = playerX - (screenW / 2);
    var startY = playerY - (screenH / 2);

    maxX = playerX + (screenW / 2);
    maxY = playerY + (screenH / 2);
    $.getJSON('mapa3.json', function (json) {
        for (x = startX; x < maxX; x = x + 32) {
            for (y = startY; y < maxY; y = y + 32) {
                intTile = json.layers[0].data[((y / 32) * 100) + (x / 32)];
                context.putImageData(getTile(intTile - 1), x - startX, y - startY);
            }
        }
    });

    var posX = (screenW - imgCharacter.width) / 2;
    var posY = (screenH - imgCharacter.height) / 2;

    context.drawImage(imgCharacter, posX, posY)
}
```

Thank you to markE for letting me know the `onload` function also needs to go outside `renderMap`, I overlooked it the first time

Comment: the following happens: screen still flickering and the character disappears when clearRect is called.. :/

Comment: screen still flickering and the character disappears when clearRect is called.. :/

Comment: @Zeaklous: You've almost got it...move your imgCharacter.onload outside renderMap and then call renderMap() inside that onload.  Then inside renderMap, just context.drawImage(imgCharacter,posX,posY)

Comment: here is my code `imgCharacter.onload = function(){
       renderMap();
       context.drawImage(imgCharacter, posX, posY);
      }` and in renderMap i put in last line the drawImage and is returning Value could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement, to this line.

Comment: Try my edited answer, I believe it is what markE is suggesting

Comment: Move the .src to after the closing brace in .onload   ;)

Comment: so weird, i guess that my character is stop and my screen still flickering! i don't think problem is the character, but the clearRect

Answer (score 2):

Load all images and other data before draw and storage them inside array.

Better use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame).

Remember, getting JSON (or other data) can take some time.